# Blazor and CSS Push/Pull

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, blazor

I'm using Blazor, and it doesn't look like CSS Push/Pull is working
If I take the stock Microsoft Sample app, and replace the table in FetchData.razor with:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>Push and Pull</h1>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4 .col-sm-push-8</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-8 .col-sm-pull-4</div>
</div>
```

The lavender block is still on the left (aka not pushed)
(sample code from [TryIt Tutorial on Push/Pull](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_ex9&stacked=h))

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The bootstrap version in the blazor default website is different from the w3schools link you have shared. The version in default blazer website is 4.3.1 and the one on w3schools is 3.4.1

As far as I can find, there is no .`col-sm-push-8` helper class in bootstrap 4. Instead you can use the class `order-*` as below:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Push and Pull</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 order-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4 .order-4</div>
    <div class="col" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output will be like this:
[image]

[Here are more details](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#order-classes)

Comment: The issue with this (now that I got to test) is that when it goes into "column" mode
you will see
.col
.col-sm-4 ,order-4

where with push/pull, being you defined/wrote  it in the other order, you get

.col-sm-4 ,order-4
.col

Answer (score 0):

The above was really close, I just changed to order-sm-xxx